# How can I get the data attribute in TypeScript with react? (drag and drop)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, drag-and-drop

I want to get the data-id from li element but it gives me an error.

```
const dragStart = (e: React.DragEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    // e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.target.getAttribute('data-id'));
  };
```

However, if I put the `any` type instead of `React.DragEvent<HTMLElement>`
, then it works. What is the correct type for `<li>` html element?

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: Property 'getAttribute' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.

Comment: Do something like (e.target as HTMLElement).getAttribute('data-id'), I don't know a better way to prove to TS that the target is an HTMLElement.

Answer (score 0):

Try change `target` to `currentTarget`